# ConnectionString or configuration for mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, hsqldb, vertex, database

I use this configuration to connect to a database hsqldb:

```
<resource Id="My DataSource" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    JdbcUrl jdbc: hsqldb: file: data / hsqldb / hsqldb
    UserName its
    Password
    JtaManaged true
</ Resource>
```

What is the configuration for a database mongodb ?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure in code - as demonstrated in the tutorial [Java - making a connection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial#JavaTutorial-MakingAConnection) or you can use connection string format with [MongoURI](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#Mongo%28com.mongodb.MongoURI%29). Here is the URI spec can be seen here [Connection String Format](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections#Connections-StandardConnectionStringFormat)